# how to display the xml tags data using force directed graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

I am referring [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1080941#index.html) link. I want to display the text content within XML tags, but since I am new to `d3` I am not able understand what changes have to made here. Can anyone help me with some clue?

the xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<flare>
  <analytics>
     <cluster>
        <agglomerativeCluster>3938</agglomerativeCluster>
        <communityStructure>3812</communityStructure>
        <mergeEdge>743</mergeEdge>
     </cluster>
     <graph>
        <test>3343</test>
        <mmmm>3353</mmmm>
        <lalala>454</lalala>
     </graph>
     <optimization>
        <AspectRatio>7074</AspectRatio>
     </optimization>
  </analytics>
</flare>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  d3.xml("path_to_your_xml_file.xml", "application/xml", function(xml) {
      d3.select("#div_that_you_want_to_modify")
        .data(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("tag_name_that_you_want_to_display"))
```

After here onwards you will be having the text content enclosed between the specified tag.
[this](https://gist.github.com/lgrammel/2772585) example will be helpful

Comment: i have seen this example but was trying to understand the tree layout example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1080941#index.html , i want to display name for these nodes some what like a tool tip. i guess i gotta read more about d3.js , thanks anyway :)